# The best way to update component after fetch data without user action in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Question like in title.
How to update component view after fetch data without user action?
Now i must click on component to update data in table. It's quite annoying.

```
export class DataStorageService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private gameTableService: GameTableService) {
  }

  getData() {
    this.db.database.ref('gameRows').on('value', snapshot => {
      this.gameTableService.processData(snapshot.val());
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
  }
}
```

```
export class GameTableService {
  gameRows: GameRowModel[] = [];
  scoresObserver: Subject<GameRowModel[]> = new Subject<GameRowModel[]>();

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {
  }

  processData(gameRow: GameRowModel) {
    this.gameRows.push(this.addRow(gameRow));
    this.playerService.getPlayers().forEach((player, index) => {
      player.updatePlayerData(gameRow.playerScores[index]);
    });
    this.scoresObserver.next(this.gameRows);
  }
}
```

```
export class GameTableComponent implements OnInit {
  playersNames: string[] = [];
  gameRows: GameRowModel[] = [];

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService,
              private gameTableService: GameTableService,
              private dataStorageService: DataStorageService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.getPlayers().forEach((player) => {
      this.playersNames.push(player.name);
    });
    this.dataStorageService.getData();
    this.gameTableService.scoresObserver.subscribe(gameRows => {
      this.gameRows = gameRows;
    });
  }
}
```

```
 <div class="col border-warning border">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">#</div>
        <div class="col text-center" *ngFor="let player of playerService.getPlayers()"> {{player.name}}</div>
      </div>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 250px;">
      <app-game-row class="text-center" *ngFor="let row of gameTableService.getGameRows()" [gameRow]="row"></app-game-row>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to use subscribe but this update field in component insted of data on view.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the component(s) and service(s) in question.

Comment: Without understanding how you are fetching the data or trying to display it, it is difficult to assist you.

Comment: Use services and use that variable to update your HTML.

Comment: @MihirPatel ok, it works when i click on component .

Comment: @JenniferS okey, now should be a bit easier.

Comment: @JarekSularz you should put that inside the ngOnInit() it ill automatically call.
create a separate function and call that function in ngOnInit().

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly..

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Try to inject this class in the GameTableComponent.

```
  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService,
              private gameTableService: GameTableService,
              private dataStorageService: DataStorageService,
              private changedetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
```

You can then anywhere in the code 'force' the changes to be detected in your ts instead of userinteraction.

```
this.changedetector.detectChanges();
```

Above will do if you put it after defining the property in the subscribe block. Let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: I catch your thought but when i put in this method in scoreObserver it does never invoked. I'm setting new value in processData which is invoked when new data are fetched.

Comment: Maybe something else is going wrong in that case, check this out.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpbcog , is it me or I dont see a getGameRows() method and getPlayers() method. Bind the HTML to the gameRows value from the component.